# Unity EditorWindow.Show isn't working at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, unity-editor

Platform: Unity 2020.3.9f1, Windows 64-bit

I'm trying to make a custom `EditorWindow` that is supposed to be displayed in response to a context menu action on a Component. However, I can't show it. When I try to... nothing happens. Nothing at all.

Code:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class TelnetConfigDialog : EditorWindow {

    private const int Margin = 10;
    private const float Spacing = 15;
    private static GUIStyle marginStyle;

    //[InitializeOnLoadMethod] static void InitTelnetConfigDialog () {   // no difference
    static TelnetConfigDialog () {
        Debug.Log("Initializing");
        DebugRemoteController.OnShowTelnetConfigDialog = () => {
            //GetWindow<TelnetConfigDialog>(true, "Configure Telnet Command", true).LogThenShow();   // no difference
            GetWindowWithRect<TelnetConfigDialog>(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200), true, "Configure Telnet Command", true).LogThenShow();
        };
    }

    private string command;
    private string args;

    private void LogThenShow () {
        Debug.Log("Showing dialog...");
        //Show(true);      // does nothing
        //Show(false);     // does nothing
        //ShowModal();     // does nothing (doesn't block main window inputs either)
        //ShowUtility();   // does nothing
        Show();
        Debug.Log(position);
        Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(this));
    }

    void OnEnable () {
        Debug.Log("OnEnable");
        marginStyle ??= new GUIStyle {
            margin = new RectOffset(Margin, Margin, Margin, Margin)
        };
    }

    void OnGUI () { // never called
        Debug.Log("OnGUI");
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(marginStyle);
        GUILayout.Label("Configure External Telnet Command", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        GUILayout.Space(Spacing);
        command = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Executable", command);
        args = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Parameters", args);
        GUILayout.Space(Spacing);
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label("", GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
        if (GUILayout.Button("OK", GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true))) Close();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Cancel", GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true))) Close();
        GUILayout.Label("", GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
    }

}
```

The static initializer hooks `LogThenShow` up to a delegate that is called in a context menu handler of a component elsewhere:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public delegate void ShowTelnetConfigDialog ();
    public static ShowTelnetConfigDialog OnShowTelnetConfigDialog;
    [ContextMenu("Configure Telnet Command...")]
    public void ConfigureTelnet () {
        OnShowTelnetConfigDialog();
    }
#endif
```

[image]

I can confirm it is working because I see the log messages each time I select the menu. However:

- The window doesn't display.
- The focus doesn't change (e.g. the main window doesn't lose focus, etc.)
- `OnGUI` is never called (the messages never show up in the log)
- And just to confirm:

  - It doesn't seem to be docked anywhere (I looked as hard as I could).
  - I looked behind the main editor window, it isn't there.
  - Its title isn't in the task bar (dunno if it should be).
  - It isn't in the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> list.
  - It isn't on another desktop (I don't have any open).
  - It isn't on another monitor (none present).

Things I've tried are marked in comments in the above code and include:

- Static initializer vs `[InitOnLoad]` method -- doesn't make a difference.
- `GetWindowWithRect` vs `GetWindow` -- doesn't make a difference.
- Various flavors of Show() -- doesn't make a difference.
- Omitting my custom marginStyle style -- doesn't make a difference.
- Completely restarting the editor and trying again -- doesn't make a difference.
- Restarting my computer (lol) -- doesn't make a difference.
- Flattery -- doesn't make a difference.
- Verbal threats -- doesn't make a difference.
- Apologizing for verbal threats -- doesn't make a difference.

There are also a bunch of seemingly strange things I've noticed. Consider this screenshot:

[image]

In particular:

- It *does* appear in the *Window -> Panels* menu.

  - Selecting it there does nothing.
  - It's present there even if I completely restart the editor and never click the context menu (is that strange?).
- It's initialized, then enabled, then `Show()` is called, but `OnGUI()` never happens.
- It thinks it is 320 x 550, placed at (0, 0). It definitely isn't, though.

  - Even if I do `GetWindowWithRect` and pass it *(0, 0, 200, 200)*, it still thinks it is *(0, 0, 320, 550)*.

So..... Under the assumption that EditorWindows are supposed to work (right?), I must be missing something, but I can't figure out what it is. It's got to be something dumb but I'm out of ideas, it's 5 AM, and I've been pulling my hair out wasting time on this relatively unimportant code for a few hours now. I think I've been following the documentation examples but I don't know.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

**Works on my machine** Unity 2020.3.10f1. Windows PC.

[image]

(Exactly copied your two code snippets - except re-used my existing script `TEST` instead of `DebugRemoteController`)

---

The position to me sounds like a "Bug" (not well documented "feature") -> it uses the given `Rect` only then, if there **never** was a window of that type open so far. As soon as you had one open and moved it around Unity stores the last window rect for that window type and re-uses that rect instead.

If you really want to be sure you can overwrite the [`position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow-position.html) directly.

---

Also what you describe about the blocking of the main menu sounds like you would want to use [`ShowModal`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.ShowModal.html) or [`ShowModalUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.ShowModalUtility.html) .. honestly I don't understand the difference between these either ^^.

**But**, also honestly, I don't really understand how exactly these are supposed to be sued since I just tried and all you get is a blanc white window until you close it because it doesn't do any repaint of the Editor while this is opened :'D

---

In general why go through that `OnShowTelnetConfigDialog` event and not directly call a method like `TelnetConfigDialog.Open` or something similar? Or e.g. using

```
public static void LogThenShow() 
{
    Debug.Log("Showing dialog...");

    var window = GetWindowWithRect<TelnetConfigDialog>(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200), true, "Configure Telnet Command", true);
   
    window.Show();
    Debug.Log(window.position);
    Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(window));
}
```

and in your behaviour

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [ContextMenu("Configure Telnet Command...")]
    public void ConfigureTelnet () {
        TelnetConfigDialog.LogThenShow();
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm going to enjoy the holiday today (Memorial Day in the US), then I'll digest this post this evening. Very odd that it works on your machine but I'm almost not surprised -- I'm starting to think that some previous API experiments may have kicked my editor into some weird state and I hit some strange edge case editor bug here. Will investigate more later as well. But first, we feast! 

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a bug, happen to me after i stop using second monitor with my laptop for a while. Editor always was on second monitor before

Logic: window creates in old saved coordinates. Coordinates present windows int out of the screen space. GUI render methods works only if its visible and present in current screen space (0 to ScreenSize)

Check if its out of the screen and do this (or any other valid coordinates) on init if it's true:

```
window.position = new Rect(0f, 0f, MinSize.x, MinSize.y);
```

MinSize is predefined variable here, so you can use anything else:

```
private static readonly Vector2 MinSize = new Vector2(400, 400);
```